# Documentation on QMetaObject::connect

Tags: c++, qt, qmetaobject

I searched the web and docs for documentation on QMetaObject::connect.   It looks intriguing because it connects signals and slots by their indices.  I see it used in a couple places including an implementation of [dynamic signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq16-dynamicqobject.html).  I also tried it and it seems to work.   Is this considered a standard use model or hack?   If it is a standard use model, did I miss the documentation?  (I did not see it under QMetaObject.)   If it is not, are there any "gotchas" I should consider?

Comment: The fact you don't find it in the public docs indicates that it's not a standard use model.

Comment: Fair enough.  I was just thinking that I might not be looking in the right area. 
  From your comment, I guess that is not the case, so thanks for the confirmation.    Do you have any insight or suggestions on the non-standard use of this method?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't. Before you going deeper into this you need to ask yourself, whether you really need it and why. If you cannot answer - better to use the standard approach, which, in my experience, works in most of the cases. Besides, if something is not documented is subject of changes. You cannot fully rely on it.

Comment: Agreed.   It is needed for space and speed.   Sufficient profiling has already taken place to require either something like this (assuming it is significantly faster), or abandoning signals and slots altogether for this particular functionality.   Also, a nice side benefit is that keeping track of indices is simpler in the target usage.